# Does CakePHP 2.2 have an end of support date? Or version?

Tags: php, cakephp

I've tried looking at the CakePHP site but there isn't a sliver of information to be found as to when is the end of support for CakePHP 2.X.

I have tried asking someone at the #cakephp irc channel and got this answer from a person

> I would take it that because 1.3 support ended when 3.x came out, that 2.x support will end when 4.x is released

However this is unverified, I hope someone can answer this and also provide a source or from someone involved with the development team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.3 support didn't end after 2.0 came out. There were 7 1.3 releases after 2.0. As ADmad mentioned we'll continue to do bugfixes for a at least a couple years, and security releases for a year or so longer. Given that we supported 1.3 for 3 years after 2.x came out, I suspect we'll do something similar with the last 2.x release as well.

Answer (score 5):

There hasn't been any decision taken to end support for CakePHP 2.x. It will continue to be maintained for the foreseeable future.

The current 2.6 series will keep getting bugfix releases and we also have a 2.7 branch where new features are added and will be released sometime in future.

So rest assured support for 2.x won't stop for months to come.

P.S. I am a member of the CakePHP dev team.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing some upgrades along the 2.8 series, and your comment helped me feel more confident about updating this, rather than porting to 3.